# PHP Replace chars by functions

Tags: php, function, preg-replace, str-replace

I try change characters by functions

```
 <?php
$string = "Hi everybody people [gal~images/articles~100~100~4]  here other imagen [gal~images/products~100~100~3]";

$regex = "/\[(.*?)\]/";
preg_match_all($regex, $string, $matches);

for($i=0; $i<count($matches[1]);$i++)
{
$match = $matches[1][$i];
$array = explode('~', $match);

//$newValuet="gal("".$array[1]."","".$array[2]."","".$array[3]."","".$array[4]."")";

$newValue="gal(".$array[1].",".$array[2].",".$array[3].",".$array[4].")";


$string = str_replace($matches[0][$i],$newValue,$string);

}

echo $string;
?>
```

The problem here :

```
$newValue="gal(".$array[1].",".$array[2].",".$array[3].",".$array[4].")";


    $string = str_replace($matches[0][$i],$newValue,$string);
```

Function no give the right results i try differents methods but continue the problems , please i see all functions but no get this works if you can answer please put me some modification of this code for i can understand , thank´s a lot for all help

MORE INFORMATION

The script generate new values this values must send thhe function of gall for insert and show replace tags and put all well , show text and tags replace

```
 $newValue="gal(".$array[1].",".$array[2].",".$array[3].",".$array[4].")";

 $string = str_replace($matches[0][$i],$newValue,$string);
```

Here the function show the gal , the function execute when must execute into str_replace for put the text , before replace the tags and continue , only this fail

P.D : I pay respect some people , i go here for send my questions howewer in many cases writte bad but english no native for me , and sure for all people here in many cases luke the people respect if no speak well , all people here need learn or need help and howewer tomorrow i can help other people or this people me , nothing more pay , thank´s

Regards

Comment: What are you trying to do? What are the input and output? What is the expected output and what do you get instead?

Comment: Have you looked at `array_map` [the docs are here](http://www.php.net/array_map), or even [the docs for `str_replace`](http://www.php.net/str_replace): the latter accepts arrays as arguments, and array map accepts a string-function-name or (in later versions of PHP a lambda style callback). Also if you expect `"gal({$arr[0]},{$arr[1]});"` to actually _call_ the function you're barking up the wrong tree...

Comment: I try replace shortcodes for galleries , nothing more , i try when start with this use explode and str_replace , but no works fine , tell me other people use other functions but finally never works , i want replace this shortcodes for galleries and this galleries can be functions or simple code , thank´s a lot

Comment: I think the most easy get chars for change and replace for functions but many people tell me about preg_replace_callback , but no results , i try all functions for do this but no get works

Comment: please, paste here the string(s) you whant to obtain with your code.

Comment: I put all code down , thank´s !

Comment: Your code prints `Hi everybody people gal(images/articles,100,100,4)  here other imagen gal(images/products,100,100,3)` ... that seems correct to me, what's wrong with it?

Answer (score 0):

**Function of gallery**

```
  <?php
    function gal($dire,$w_size,$h_size,$cols)
    {
    $n_images=0;

    $dir=opendir("$dire");
    while($file=readdir($dir))
    {
    if ($file!="." && $file!=".." && $file!="Thumbs.db" && $file!="index.html" && $file!=".htaccess" && $file!="config.dat")
    {
    $n_images++;
    $imagenes[]=$file;
    }

    }
    closedir($dir);

    $num_img="".$n_images."";
    $num_img_cols="".$cols."";
    $num_filas="".ceil($num_img/$num_img_cols)."";

    echo '<table width="10%" border="0" cellpadding="3" cellspacing="2" align="center">
    <tr> 
    <td colspan="'.$num_img_cols.'">&nbsp;</td>
    </tr><tr>';

    $x=1;

    for ($j=0;$j<$n_images;$j++)
    {
    print "<td align='center'>";

    //echo '<img src="'.$dire.'/'.$imagenes[$j].'" width="'.$w_size.'" height="'.$h_size.'">';

    print "<a href='".$dire."/".$imagenes[$j]."' class='highslide' onclick=\"return hs.expand(this,{slideshowGroup:'group1',align:'center'})\">";
    print '<img src="indexer_resizer.php?ruta_f='.$dire.'/&image='.$imagenes[$j].'&new_width='.$w_size.'&new_height='.$h_size.'" border="0" alt="Pulse para Ampliar" title="Pulse para Ampliar">
    </a>';

    if ($x%$num_img_cols==0)
    {
    print "</tr>";
    }
    $x++;
    }

    echo "</table>";
    }
    ?>

**Function for replace tags**

     <?php
    $string = "Hola todos os presento una nueva galeria  [galt~imagenes/articulos~100~100~4]  Aqui otra más [gal~imagenes/productos~100~100~3]";

    $regex = "/\[(.*?)\]/";
    preg_match_all($regex, $string, $matches);

    for($i=0; $i<count($matches[1]);$i++)
    {
    $match = $matches[1][$i];
    $array = explode('~', $match);

    //$newValuet="gal("".$array[1]."","".$array[2]."","".$array[3]."","".$array[4]."")";

    $newValue="gal(".$array[1].",".$array[2].",".$array[3].",".$array[4].")";


    $string = str_replace($matches[0][$i],$newValue,$string);

    }

    echo $string;
    ?>
```

This is all function and you can see here , the script use 2 things the function for see gallery and the script for replace and show gallery , but no works fine

The script generate new values this values must send thhe function of gall for insert and show replace tags and put all well , show text and tags replace

```
 $newValue="gal(".$array[1].",".$array[2].",".$array[3].",".$array[4].")";

 $string = str_replace($matches[0][$i],$newValue,$string);
```

Here the function show the gal , the function execute when must execute into str_replace for put the text , before replace the tags and continue , only this fail

P.D : I pay respect some people , i go here for send my questions howewer in many cases writte bad but english no native for me , and sure for all people here in many cases luke the people respect if no speak well , all people here need learn or need help and howewer tomorrow i can help other people or this people me , nothing more pay , thank´s

Regards

Comment: Please i pay some patient for this question , i put my question here because i think here can help me and no pay more things , for this only pay respect nothing more , for othher siide , in this function and script no work me this :

Comment: $newValue="gal(".$array[1].",".$array[2].",".$array[3].",".$array[4].")";
$string = str_replace($matches[0][$i],$newValue,$string); i try use callback but no work me , the script basically replace code into [] and put the function gallery , happend no works or the script show bad the order and no replace when must do it , thank´s

Comment: Apologies, I misread the thread and I thought your answer was a question. Please edit your answer so that I can cancel my downvote (I cannot change my vote unless you edit your post)

Answer (score 0):

To capture those portions of the string try:

```
$string = "Hi everybody people [gal~images/articles~100~100~4]  here other imagen [gal~images/products~100~100~3]";

preg_match_all('/\[(.+)\]/ismU, $string, $matches);
```

or

```
preg_match_all('/\[(\w+)\~([a-z0-9\/]+)\~(\d+)\~(\d+)\~(\d+)\]/ismU, $string, $matches);
```

The last one results a bit more complicated structure of `$matches` but prooves that you'll catch exactly the data you need.

Comment: The problem no get the content of this tags the problem replace this tags for the function of gallery which read the directory and insert the pics and replace this tags i think only can do this with jquery or iframe because in php it´s impossible do this i work in this 5 days ago i have all and only fail replace the tags from the text and insert in each tag one fuction which create one gallery , howewer php it´s limit for do this because at the moment nothing can put solution to this and i try many times , Thank´s